# Alerting the text that is inside chosen jquery dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I am using [jquery chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), with the specific component [*multiple select*](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#no-results-text-support).

I want to listen if something is typed in the chosen text bar and alert the content typed in that.

To achieve that I have:

#### HTML:

```
<select id="searchZip" name="types[]" multiple class="searchZip chosen-select-no-results" tabindex="12">
</select>
```

#### JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        '.chosen-select': {},
        '.chosen-select-deselect': {
            allow_single_deselect: true
        },
        '.chosen-select-no-single': {
            disable_search_threshold: 10
        },
        '.chosen-select-no-results': {
            no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!'
        },
        '.chosen-select-width': {
            width: "95%"
        }
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
        $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
</script>
```

I want to call *alert()* if something is typed in the search box. How can I do that?

```
$("#searchZip").chosen().change( alert("a"); );
```

When I do this, I always get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

How can I call alert with the input that is typed in the chosen input?

Comment: Remove ; after the alert statement

Comment: Now, alert is coming by default

Comment: Yes, you'll need to replace it with a `function` like: `function() { alert("a"); }`. If nothing is happening it's because the `change`-event is not firing.

Comment: Also you'll need to add some items to the `select` or you can not choose anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the alert box there should not be any semicolon as it terminates the statement..

just write `.change(alert("a"));`

Comment: Now, alert is coming by default

Comment: document.getElementById('searchZip');
      function namet()
     {
  alert("Hey");
     }

Comment: @SulthanA You have to trigger jquery click event

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the following line from this:

```
$("#searchZip").chosen().change( alert("a"); );
```

To this:

```
$("#searchZip").chosen().change( alert("a") );
```

When JavaScript sees a `;`, it assumes it is the end of the line. Since your `;` was before inside the `.change()`, JavaScript did not see a closing `)` for `.change()`, so it producedthe following error stating that it was `missing ) after argument list`

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: Now, alert is coming by default

Answer (score 0):

That line passed to function *.change()* should be a function. `alert("a")` is a function invocation (statement). That invocation could be moved into lambda (anonymous) function:

```
$("#searchZip").chosen().change( function() {alert("a"); });
```

Or a named function could be used:

```
function alertA() {
    alert("a");
}
$("#searchZip").chosen().change( alertA );
```

For more information, refer to the [MDN documentation on functions as callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Creating_JavaScript_callbacks_in_components#JavaScript_functions_as_callbacks).

The "[documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)" is a little lacking as far as the arguments passed to *.change()*, but change calls [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) so the arguments are:

- **event**: [event](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event)

  *contains information about the event*
- **extraParam**: [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

  *contains information about the selected option*

The extraParam can be used to get the text of the selected option:

```
function alertA(event, result) {
    alert(result.selected);
}
```

See a demonstration of this below.

```js
$('.chosen-select-no-results').chosen({
  no_results_text: 'Oops, nothing found!'
});

function alertA(event, result) {
  alert(result.selected);
}
$("#searchZip").chosen().change(alertA);
```

```html
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select id="searchZip" name="types[]" multiple class="searchZip chosen-select-no-results" tabindex="12">
<option>Cat</option>
<option>Dog</option>
<option>Zebra</option>
</select>
```